# is it time to throw up my hands and cast?

Tags: python, attributes, mypy, python-typing, python-3.10

##### Knowing full well that typing.cast should be reserved for the most specialest of special occasions, is this a time to cast away anyway??

Adding custom attributes to function objects is a pretty neat trick (e.g. [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)), and, thank the good Lord for Python, it's trivial to do so with setattr.  Unfortunately, it's not so trivial to have those shiny new attributes show up in autocomplete lookaheads or pass muster with static type checkers and linters (without implicitly or explicitly resorting to Any).  For example,

```py
def badfoo():
    """not gonna work"""
    print("oh no")
setattr(badfoo, "new_attr", "here it is")
badfoo.new_attr
```

works at runtime but the new attribute doesn't show up in autocomplete nor is it recognized by mypy or pylint:

```py
pylint: testvcd.py:38:0: E1101: Function 'badfoo' has no 'new_attr' member (no-member)
mypy:   testvcd.py:38: error: "Callable[[], Any]" has no attribute "new_attr"
```

Adding the attribute using an untyped decorator prevents the pylint and mypy errors, but it doesn't solve the autocomplete issue or allow for type checks on the appended attributes(s).

### EDIT

Thanks, @Markus Unterwaditzer, for recommending a much more concise method for obtaining the desired results as well as a much more precise statement of the issue I'm attempting to address, namely, adding a statically discoverable, type-checkable custom attribute to a function.  @Markus' [recommended method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73420163/15319863) (with some slight additions to preserve the decorated function's signature) defines the decorator as:

```py
"""attribute_decorator.py: define a `with_attribute` decorator"""

from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Callable, ParamSpec

T = TypeVar("T")
T_ATTR = TypeVar("T_ATTR")
P = ParamSpec("P")

class _FuncWithAttr(Generic[P, T, T_ATTR]):
    new_attr: T_ATTR
    def __call__(self: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        ...

def with_attribute(value: T_ATTR) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], _FuncWithAttr[P, T, T_ATTR]]:
    def inner(f: Callable[P, T]) -> _FuncWithAttr[P, T, T_ATTR]:
        f.new_attr = value  # type: ignore
        return f  # type: ignore
    return inner
```

and usage:

```py
from attribute_decorator import with_attribute

@with_attribute({"my": "dict"})
def foo(some: int, args: int) -> int:
    return some + args

# typechecks!
x = {"your": "dict"}
x |= foo.new_attr
assert foo(1, 2) == 3
```

As shown, Markus' method still requires some "# type: ignore" directives. **I'm still hoping someone might come along and demonstrate a method that pulls this off without casts (used in my original solution below) **or** ignores (used in Markus' solution above), so if you know any mypy devs who are both bored and benevolent, please send them my way... XD**

##### Stop reading here unless you're interested in my original, more confusing example ;)

As a chronic circumventionalist, I set about fumbling my way around those limitations in what seemed a semi-coherent manner and, lo and behold, I managed to crack the code... in the decorator use case... kinda... **

**I'm relying on typing.cast to make it work.  I wrote the following "RollingDefaults" decorator as a (slightly) practical example that demonstrates the **typing mechanism**.  I'm sure it would fail at its stated purpose for lots of use cases, but that's beside the point.  The question is whether or not I could achieve the same discovery/static checker benefits **without** the reliance on typing.cast. Note that these benefits extend to enforcement of type checks on any and all appended attributes as well as the args/kwargs passed to the wrapped function, so cast seems like a fairly effective solution, at least on the surface.

### rolling_defaults.py

```py
"""use the most recently passed parameter values as the defaults for
subsequent calls to the wrapped function and provide visibility to the
current (rolling) and original default parameter values"""
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar, cast


T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


class _RollingDefaultFunc(Generic[P, T]):
    rolling_defaults: dict[str, Any]
    original_defaults: dict[str, Any]

    def __call__(self: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        ...

    def reset_defaults(self):
        """return to original defaults"""


class RollingDefaults:
    """add "rolling_defaults", "original_defaults", and "reset_defaults"
    attributes to wrapped function
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.func: Callable
        self._defaults: dict[str, Any]
        self._rolling_defaults: dict[str, Any]

    def __call__(self, func: Callable[P, T]) -> _RollingDefaultFunc[P, T]:
        self.func = func
        self._rolling_defaults = {
            k: v() if isinstance(v, type) else None
            for k, v in func.__annotations__.items()
            if k != "return"
        }
        true_defaults = [] if func.__defaults__ is None else list(func.__defaults__)
        if func.__kwdefaults__ is not None:
            true_defaults.extend(list(func.__kwdefaults__.values()))
        type_defaults = list(self._rolling_defaults.values())
        for diff_idx in reversed(range(len(type_defaults) - len(true_defaults))):
            true_defaults.insert(0, type_defaults[diff_idx])
        self._defaults = dict(zip(self._rolling_defaults, true_defaults))
        self._rolling_defaults |= self._defaults

        @wraps(func)
        def rolling_wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            return self._wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

        setattr(rolling_wrapper, "rolling_defaults", self.rolling_defaults)
        setattr(rolling_wrapper, "original_defaults", self.original_defaults)
        setattr(rolling_wrapper, "reset_defaults", self.reset_defaults)

        #
        # Is cast a good option here?
        #
        return cast(_RollingDefaultFunc[P, T], rolling_wrapper)
        #
        # Is there a better way that doesn't use the cast above?
        #

    @property
    def rolling_defaults(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        """parameter defaults for the next call"""
        return self._rolling_defaults

    @property
    def original_defaults(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        """original defaults"""
        return self._defaults

    def reset_defaults(self):
        """reset to originals"""
        self._rolling_defaults |= self._defaults

    def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        self._rolling_defaults |= dict(zip(self._defaults, args))
        self._rolling_defaults |= kwargs
        return self.func(**self._rolling_defaults)
```

### testroll.py

```py
from rolling_defaults import RollingDefaults

@RollingDefaults()
def foo(bar: int = 1, *, baz: str = "test") -> str:
    return f"{bar=}; {baz=}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(foo())
    print(foo.rolling_defaults)
    print(foo(11, baz="passed"))
    print(foo.rolling_defaults)
    print(foo())
    foo.reset_defaults()
    print(foo.rolling_defaults)
    print(foo())
```

### Result

Autocomplete works for the new attributes and displays the correct call signature, and pylint / mypy no longer raise attribute errors but do raise appropriate errors on bad assignments to the appended attributes and / or bad arg values passed in the call to foo.
Output:

```py
>python testroll.py
bar=1; baz='test'
{'bar': 1, 'baz': 'test'}
bar=11; baz='passed'
{'bar': 11, 'baz': 'passed'}
bar=11; baz='passed'
{'bar': 1, 'baz': 'test'}
bar=1; baz='test'
```

Comment: I found this gem in the mypy docs, so maybe this is fine?  Not sure if casting to the generic function type is going to cause other headaches tho... https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators

Comment: I would suggest to trim down the question to the first few paragraphs, it already succinctly describes the problem. Let me know if I misunderstood though.

Comment: Whether something shows up in autocomplete is really a separate issue from typing. But really, you're asking how to making dynamic behavior visible statically, a contradiction.

Comment: @chepner, I disagree on grounds of the standard functools library decorator I referenced in the question, lru_cache (among others). These built in decorators exhibit exactly the desired behavior.

Comment: @chepner, could you elaborate on what makes the functools decorator use case different from the desired behavior?  It's obviously employing a different (and difficult to emulate) mechanism to achieve the same results, so if you have any insight as to the difference between the two (or, even better, how to employ the same tactics in my own projects), it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If the core question is "how can I make setting an attribute on a function type-safe-ish", the answer is that, in some ways, you can encapsulate the type-unsafety:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Callable

T = TypeVar("T")

class FunctionWithAttribute(Generic[T]):
    new_attr: str
    __call__: T

def with_attribute(value: str) -> Callable[[T], FunctionWithAttribute[T]]:
    def inner(f: T) -> FunctionWithAttribute[T]:
        f.new_attr = value  # type: ignore
        return f  # type: ignore

    return inner


@with_attribute("hello")
def foo(some: int, args: int) -> int:
    return some + args

# typechecks!
x: str = foo.new_attr + ""
assert foo(1, 2) == 3
```

Inside of the decorator, you have quite a bit of casting/ignoring going on, outside you don't.

one concern: if you apply this decorator to a callable that doesn't allow you to set attributes, mypy won't catch it and your code will still crash at import

Comment: Thanks! I'll digest this a bit more carefully tomorrow and either respond by marking this as the answer or giving you an explanation as to why I didn't do so.

Comment: This method is more concise / elegant while providing the desired type checking. The only thing missing was function signature autocomplete, but 3.10 has ParamSpec for that. I'm updating the OP to demonstrate, but I'm hoping a bored mypy dev might come along to show us how it's done without a cast or the ignore directives (which aren't exactly the same, but similar in spirit). If not, I'll accept this as the answer in a couple days.

Comment: @SamHartzog that's not really how you're supposed to use stackoverflow at all. if you have a solution post it as its own answer

Comment: This one's a bit of a fine line, no?  Your method was a _better_ method IMO, but if there's a way to do this without ignores OR casts, _that's_ what I'm really after.  My goal was to use your example to clarify the use case (giving credit where due), but to make it clear that it wasn't quite "all the way there" in case someone out there knows a completely type safe method. What's the right way to go about it in a situation like that?  Should I have just added an answer of my own rather than editing the OP?